# How to add autocomplete searchBox to Gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

How can I add autocomplete searchBox to google map using Gmaps4Rails gem?

So I searched the [google developer documents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete). I figured out that I have to use this code sample to achieve my purpose
 `new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapsearch'))`

But I don't know how should I integrate that code with my gmaps4rails code.
Btw I have done it without using gmaps4rails(just pure javascript from google API) but haven't figured out how to change the gmaps4rails' coffee script code for my purpose

```
@buildMap =(markers)->
  handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } 
  handler.buildMap { provider: {panControl: false,streetViewControl: false,zoomControl: false}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers,draggable:true)
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: Can you please complete your question with more data... Maybe some code that can help understand what you need could help.